# i want to delete the particular component on clicking the delete icon. How can I do that?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
const deleteAlert= ({ item }) =>
     {
      Alert.alert("Delete Notification ?", "", [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancelled"),
          style:'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: "Delete",
          onPress: () => item.filter((item) => select && item.id === selectedId),
        },
      ]);
    }
```

I tried running this but it gives an error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item. filter').

How to correct this issue?

Comment: How to you use `deleteAlert`? And what is select and selectedId?

Comment: If you want to remove specific element from an array then you need to check the inverse of equality, i.e. `item.filter((item) => select && item.id !== selectedId)`, otherwise you'll keep the one you want to delete and remove everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the error you get is

```
Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item. filter').
```

I think deleteAlert is not passed with an object with key as item and list of item as value.

You need to call deleteAlert with

```
const items = [
  {
    id:1
  },
  {
    id:2
  }
]

deleteAlert({item:items});
```

Also I don't know how you get access to selectedId and selected.

Better advise is to pass the selected Id to the deleteAlert method as well and not convolute by passing object.

```
deleteAlert(items, selectedId)
```